# Exception when presenting UIAlertController with a custom UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift, exception, uialertcontroller, uiwindow

I have an app, where at one point I am displaying an UIAlertController from withing an viewcontroller using the following code:

```
let menu = UIAlertController(title: "Menu", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
menu.addAction(cancel)
self.present(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is working fine, as long as in AppDelegate I am not setting the UIWindow, but leaving it nil.
As I need to overwrite the default UIWindow with a custom one, I have the following code in AppDelegate.swift:

```
var window: UIWindow? = ThemedWindow()
```

ThemedWindow:

```
import Foundation
class ThemedWindow: UIWindow {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        //clear the background color of all table views, so we can see the background
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

When presenting the UIAlertController I get now the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIAlertController is expected to have a visual style during transitioning'
```

Any idea, what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks.

**Update:**

In AppDelegate I changed the initialization of the window to

```
var window: UIWindow? = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

And am also getting the crash. So it seems, that it is not related to the subclass, but to the assignment itself

**Update 2**

Problem solved: It came out, that defining the window with the screen bounds during initialization is not a good idea (most probably the UIScreen dimensions are not ready at this stage).

To solve the issue, I had to add the following line to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
window!.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

Now it works

Comment: Does it happen when you remove `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`? As I see it, you don't need to subclass the window. Why don't you just change the `backgroundColor` on the default window?

Comment: In fact, in my project I am doing more than just setting the background color, this is here just for simplicity.
I removed the tableview line, but unfortunately didn't make a difference

Comment: Have you found what makes a difference? Would it work with a completely empty class `ThemedWindow`?

Comment: I gave it a try and cleared the whole content of ThemedWindow: same result

Comment: @Sulthan: Thanks for your help. I found a solution and updated the question :)

Comment: I am glad you found the root problem by yourself but it's interesting that I am using the `frame: UIScreen.main.bounds` initializer at various apps, too and never had the problem before...

Comment: That is really interesting...Don't know, what the reason is, I also wasn't able to find any information in the web about such an issue, but it is clearly reproducable for me, that this line is needed in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Again, beside the alert views everything is working in the app without adding this line. Do you use the UIAlertController in your apps ?